# Extracting translatable strings from twig template

Tags: php, internationalization, twig, symfony, silex

I'm trying to create a `messages.pot` file for my application using the [workflow described in the docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/i18n.html#extracting-template-strings). Unfortunately, I can't get this to work. I can render the cached version of my templates, but when running `xgettext`, no strings are recognized.

After inspecting a cached template, I see calls being made to

```
echo $this->env->getExtension('translator')->getTranslator()->trans("Yadda", array(), "messages");
```

I guess `xgettext` only looks for calls to `gettext()`, `dcgettext()`, etc. Am I missing something here? How to fix this?

I'm using Silex 2.0.3-dev, twig 1.24.1, twig-bridge 3.0.7.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem... i found no way to get it by the translator component, so i wrote and node js script to parse the twig files...

here is the pastebin link... if u like to update the file or something please contact me probably we can put it on github...

http://pastebin.com/WSDsABfz

Comment: Thanks! I've made some quick improvements to your script: https://gist.github.com/bjornpost/aa2373f6c450b9a8c0fde7becaff5683